# image corrupted after reading image file in chunk

Tags: python, django, image

so i am trying to ready image file form django request in chunks, the django filehandler chunks method does not work well for me, so i created a custom on, it works but the end product wasnt what i was expecting, so after reading the files in chunks and putting them together somehow the image get corrupts and i dont have any solution for it.

```
def process_download_with_progress(self, image_file, length):

    process_recoder = ProgressRecorder(self)
    print('Upload: Task Started')
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    chunk_size = 0
    
    for chunk in read_chunk(image_file.file, length):  
        chunk_size += 1      
        buffer.write(chunk)
        process_recoder.set_progress(chunk_size, length, description=f'uploaded {chunk_size*length} bytes of the file')
    buffer.seek(0)
    image = ImageFile(buffer, name=image_file.name)
    fs.save(image_file.name, content=image)
    return 'Done'

def read_chunk(file_object, chunk_size=125):
    while True:
        file =  file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not file:
            break
        yield file
```

so this my code, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the point of this?  If `image_file.file` exists, then the entire file has already been uploaded.  What are you gaining here?  And it's clear that 125 bytes is a ridiculously small value for a chunk.  A megabyte would be reasonable, but I don't see why you're doing this at all.

Comment: @TimRoberts image_file is a Django in-memory file wrapper around the original file, to access the file itself you use file

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables. You could also open file in some hex editor to see what you get in file. Maybe you will see something interesting which would help you to resolve problem. Simply you have to debug it.

Comment: it would be simpler if you could create minimal working code which we could run and see problem.

Comment: @user15317824  I know that.  It's already buffered.  So, what do you gain by chunking like this?

Comment: @TimRoberts what i am trying to do is save the chunks of image and assemble them into the original image

Comment: Yes, I know.  Why are you doing that?  Why aren't you just copying from `image_file.file` directly?  Why the chunking, with a ridiculously small chunk size?